# Анимация колеблющейся точки

Tags: python, c++, matlab

Есть задача - создать анимацию, на которой будет колебаться точка в одной оси (направление не важно) с определенной задаваемой частотой.
Точность (соответствие частоты этих колебаний реальности) важна, так как на основе этой анимации будет выполнена калибровка одной штуки, соответственно важен и рантайм.

У меня три вопроса:
Какие подводные?
На чем лучше это написать (python/matlab/etc.)
Какие фреймворки/библиотеки лучше использовать?

Comment: Я бы вообще `Unity 3D` взял, но там `C#`. Хотя и для питона вроде были библиотеки с физикой, но названия не помню.

Comment: Можно сделать метроном в браузере. Будет довольно точным и тикать будет.

Answer (score 1):

Метроном в командной строке:

```
import math
import time
import sys


freq = float(sys.argv[2])
width = int(sys.argv[1])

start = time.time()
last_p = 0
while True:
    c = math.fmod(freq * (time.time() - start), 1)
    p = round(width * c)
    if p < last_p:
        print('\r' + ' ' * width, end='\r', flush=True)
        last_p = 0
    while p > last_p:
        print('X', end='', flush=True)
        last_p += 1
```

> $ python metronome.py 80 0.5